# Can I just make up attributes on my HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html

Am I allowed to add whatever attributes I want to HTML tags such that I can retrieve their value later on using javascript? For example:

```
<a href="something.html" hastooltip="yes" tipcolour="yellow">...</a>
```

If that's not going to work, how would you store arbitrary pieces of information like this?

**Edit:** Since it appears that making up HTML attributes isn't technically valid, I've rephrased the second part of this question into its own question here: [How to store arbitrary data for some HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432174/)

Comment: +1 I am a big fan of using data- attributes for declarative wiring up behavior, isntead of using classes.  However, something like tipcolour I would try to use a class if I could get the CSS right.  In other words, attributes for behavior, classes for style.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In HTML5, yes. You just have to prefix them with `data-`. See [the spec](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp).

Of course, this implies you should be using the HTML5 doctype (`<!doctype html>`), even though browsers don't care.

Comment: HTML5 is still in draft, this is not a safe recommendation

Comment: Umm, this specification is meant to be used before going final. http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#When_will_we_be_able_to_start_using_these_new_features.3F

Comment: This won't break anything anymore than arbitarily choosing attributes, and it's valid for a future spec, smiles all round!

Comment: @annakata, What is unsafe about this recommendation? What will it break?

Comment: I think he meant unsafe as in, the spec could change at any time before 'going final'. And if something does change, something will break.

Comment: Don't worry too much about the spec not being finalised. Finalised specifications might change/be superceded. Browsers might not implement the specification. Just make sure you test for your users, and evolve with the web!

Comment: Note also that jQuery allows you to read these attributes, and in turn store more complicated data(but the methods that modify the values may not show up in the HTML as attributes).  In essence data- can be used to declare data in the HTML, which can then be read using .data(...) but writing data uses a more efficient method than modifying HTML.  I say all this just cause it is initially confusing for someone who is new to using jquery's .data API: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 24):

Well, you can always create your own DTD to get new valid attributes for your tags. Browser won't hiccup, you should test your JavaScript if you can access these custom attributes. Or you can use the existing facilities provided by HTML and CSS. You can use multiple classes like

```
<a href="..." class="class-one class-two has-tooltip">
```

For the colour selection I strongly discourage you to use hard-coded colour names in your HTML, you have CSS for declaring styles. Use the class attribute as a hook for the CSS declaration, and choose *semantic* class names, for example

HTML:

```
<a href="..." class="has-tooltip common-tooltip">
<a href="..." class="has-tooltip long-tooltip">
```

CSS:

```
a.has-tooltip {
   colour: red;
}
a.common-tooltip {
   background: #ddd;
}
a.long-tooltip {
   background: #ebf;
}
```

And in your JavaScript code you can generate elements with classes like "long-tooltip" and "common-tooltip" instead of "yellow-tooltip", so you won't contradict yourself in case of redesigning the page to have green tooltips.

Comment: the example i gave really was just an example: the data i'd be storing could be anything really, not just colours and whatnot.

Answer (score 4):

You can. The page will not pass verification, however most browsers will accept it.

It is almost certainly the wrong way of doing it. Try using class="hasTooltip_yes tipcolour_yellow"

Comment: you don't think that bastardising the class attribute is even more wrong though?

Comment: If you bastardise the class attribute it will still validate so in terms of adhering to standards your still better off.

Comment: Just because you are adhering to standards, doesn't mean you have the best possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the information you want to store you should look at some of the other attributes available. These don't look like good candidates, but 'rel' has been used for lots of interesting things.

Comment: according to the spec, the rel attribute can only contain LinkTypes eg: start next prev chapter

Comment: But, the spec doesn't define an authoritative list of link types, and in fact leaves room for expansion