# Is it bad to add a css class that doesn't exist?

Tags: asp.net, css, jquery-selectors

I want to add a bunch of classes to some text fields so i can get their values with jquery. This seems like standard practice when using jQuery and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744455/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-add-extra-attributes-to-html-elements) suggests it as the answer but how does this affect page loading? Won't it be trying to find all these classes? I have been told in the past to try minimise the amount of classes used on controls.

I have about 12 controls i'll want to add unique classes to to get their value. I am using asp.net so I can't use the id. I also can't use the ClientID as the controls are in a table (but only 1 set of controls will show at any one time).

e.g.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtValue1" runat="server" CssClass="value1" Text='value1' />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtValue2" runat="server" CssClass="value2" Text='value2' />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtValue3" runat="server" CssClass="value3" Text='value3' />
...

var value1 = $('.value1').val();
var value2 = $('.value2').val();
var value3 = $('.value3').val();
```

And none of the class names will exist in css.

Thanks

**Edit:**

I know this works but I was more curious about the affect it had on page loading. There was an answer (seems to be deleted now) that said something like the html parser ignores the classes. The css parser will only look at classes that are defined. So it sounds like it would be completely ignored and have no affect on page load. Is this right?

Comment: I don't think that Edit is right. As best as I can tell, it will search the CSS for the class name, not find it and move on. I'd say that it would add some amount to page load but it is negligible. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Writing_Efficient_CSS#How_the_Style_System_Matches_Rules http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#UseEfficientCSSSelectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you are using ASP.Net so you can't use the ID parameter, but you can. In JQuery you can get the controls using the below

```
var value1 = $('[ID$=yourID]').val();
```

For more info on JQuery Selectors check out: [JQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [Attribute Ends With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

The above selector basically finds the id ENDING in "yourID" so ignoring all the masterpages extra text at the start. You just have to make sure these are unique. e.g. don't have ids like "HSBC" and "SBC" as the above selector on "SBC" will find both.

Comment: Even though it seems fine to add the classes this seems like a more elegant solution to my current problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is okay to use a CSS class that doesn't exist, but if they are unique you want to use `id`, not `class`.

Comment: Hi Logan, I can't use ID because it will get converted to something like ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_txtValue1. This was used in the existing code, I am now working on it because the layout changed, changing the id. I now have to hunt for all the broken javascript.

Comment: You can use the ID and should... see my answer below on how to use it in JQuery with asp.net

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a problem. The only times I've had problems with non-existant classes or ID's is one time I had an onclick reference an ID that didn't exist. This messed things up...Other than that I think classes are pretty harmless. I'd be interested to know though..

Any other thoughts??

Answer (score 0):

Which version of asp.net are you using?  In asp.net 4.0, you have the ability to use unmangled ids.  It looks like the simplest solution would be to set ClientIDMode="Static" to all of your textboxes and then refer by id.  Otherwise, sure, I've created classes that don't exist to refer to things.... all the time.

Edit: (in response to your comment about the effect page load).

I think your question about having extra classes in a div that are not currently used is not a bad question (at least in a theoretical sense), and I honestly don't know the precise answer.  I do believe any effect is quite minuscule. If you consider best practices to write html, you generally write and structure the HTML, with it's classes, before you write the CSS.  This means at the time you write the CSS, certainly some classes will not be used.  Indeed, after styling the basic tags (`body`, `h1`, `a`, etc), you may find you never need to create selectors with those classes for some particular design.  And yet for the next design, you might need those classes.  I'm pretty sure the technology behind CSS was built with those kinds of scenarios in mind, and I bet millions if not billions of pages on the internet follow that exact scenario, especially if they use something like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), which adds classes to the html element of the page as a way of providing you classes you can select against considering the possible capabilities of the current browser.   You may never need those classes, but they are there if you need them.

Comment: I tried this but the id ended up being "I". I'd say this is because it's in the table. What I said in a comment above, isn't quite right. It would actually be ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_efX_txtValue1, where X is the row number.