# set text and value on div and span

Tags: html

i'd like to set and retrieve 2 values for a div and span
1. text (displayed on screen)
2. value (for backend purposes)

what's the correct way to do this?
there's innerhtml, value, val(), text, html....i'm confused
do these serve different purposes? they seem interchangeable

Comment: Set and retrieve them from where? Describe the full lifecycle of the values you mention.

Comment: within javascript event handlers e.g i have a dialog with a list of spans. initially when it loads I want to set each spans value and text to "aValue" and "aText" respectively. The text and values are different for each span. Then when each span is clicked I want a div at the top of the dialog to take on the text and value of the selected span. Then the dialog is hidden. Then i need to access the divs (selected item) text and value in another function/handler so that I can do stuff with it.

Comment: Div and span don't have value attributes.
An example would be helpful.

Comment: Isn't this the answer to your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432174/how-to-store-arbitrary-data-for-some-html-tags

Answer (score 0):

One correct way to accomplish this is to set a "data attribute" of the div to the internal or server value, with the user-visible value being inside the div:

```
<div data-info="internal">visible</div>
```

This shows it done statically. You can also create and set the attributes of a DIV DOM node in JavaScript. Ask me if you want an example.

Sorry for the 8-year delay in answering.

See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*