# how to get generated html form with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamically-generated

I have this form

```
<form id="myForm">
<input name="foo" value=""  />
<input name="bar" value=""  />
... other dynamic input generated by jquery
</form>
```

How do I get all the html, including the values ​​of "foo" and "bar" and other input values?

I do not need the values, but all the generated html including the values ​​entered by users.

```
$ ('#myform').html()
```

returns the html of the form WITHOUT the values ​​entered by users

Comment: This is the correct behavior -- the user-entered values are NOT part of the HTML or the DOM. You must obtain them separately using `.val()`. Depending on your actual objective, you might also use [`$form.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to slurp all the form values up at once.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually set the value attributes like this:

```
$('#myForm input').each(function(){ 
    $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
});
console.log($('#myForm').html());
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7g6CP/1/

Be careful what you do with this however, you might be opening yourself up to some security concerns.