# Change background images on click

Tags: javascript

I have a div with the id "art". This div should have the background "S1_img1.jpg". Below the div there's a button and when I click it, the background image has to change to "S1_img2.jpg".

When I click it again it has to change to "S1_img3.jpg" and it goes on like that. However, img4 is the last one. Meaning when the div background is currently set as img4 and I click the button again, it must change back to img1.

I am trying to accomplish this by using javascript but I can't get it to work.

1) When I use the code below, the image does not show as the background, even if I am sure the image path is correct.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("art").style.backgroundImage = "url(content/art/S1/S1_img1.jpg)";</script>
```

2) How can I make it so that it changes the background when I click the button as I described?

At the moment the onClick of the button executes the javascript function "count();".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var img = 1;

function count() {
    img = img + 1;
    document.getElementById("content").style.backgroundImage = "url(content/art/S3/S3_img1.jpg)";
}
</script>
```

Comment: be good to make a fiddle of this be easier to diagnose - http://jsfiddle.net/ . Have you set a height on the div you're changing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the condition for that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var img = 1;

function count() {
img = img + 1;
document.getElementById("content").style.backgroundImage = "url(content/art/S3/S3_img"+img+".jpg)";
if (img==4) img=0;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use HTML5, you can use custom attribute (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/432201/4375327)). It's better than using global variables, this way you can manage several element's background.

```
<div style="background-image:url(content/art/S1/S1_img1.jpg);cursor:pointer"
     onclick="toggleBackgroundImage(this)">a</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleBackgroundImage(element) {
    var idbgrank = parseInt(element.getAttribute("data-idbgrank"));
    idbgrank = idbgrank ? idbgrank + 1 : 2;
    element.setAttribute("data-idbgrank", idbgrank)
    if (idbgrank > 4) return;
    element.style.backgroundImage = "url(content/art/S1/S1_img" + idbgrank + ".jpg)";
    alert(element.style.backgroundImage); //remove it ;)
}
</script>
```

See fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/g40hL0jc/3/

(the result is visible through alert() call, you'll just have to remove it).