# Alternative to passing data in onClick?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page which lists all database records from a certain server.
Along side each row are a few buttons which allow you to rename or delete records.

```
INPUT( _value='Rename', _type="button", _class='appbutton', _onclick='renameApplication({0},"{1}")'.format(app.id,app.name))
```

Which generates something like:

```
<input class="appbutton" type="button" value="Rename" onclick="renameApplication(3,"My Application")"></input>
```

(The backend templating engine is web2py, but that's not really important.)

I am generating these buttons dynamically. Currently I pass the data each button needs through onClick.

According to [jQuery.click() vs onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick) I shouldn't be doing this anymore. But if that is the case, how should I be passing data so that each button click can use dynamic data written server side (the application ID and name in this instance.)

I can't do dom traversal through the record to grab the data because the row structure might change.

I can't use custom attributes because I need to support less than HTML 5, and I'm not going to modify the doctype! ([Can I add custom attribute to HTML tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-custom-attribute-to-html-tag))

The only thing I can think of is to put data in the id attribute then parse it, but that seems very hackish.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to use an [jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to hook the event on every button. You may put the server  Id in an data attribute which is understood by jQuery, without major issues:

```
<input class="appbutton" type="button" value="Rename" data-id="3"></input>
```

Then the js:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.appbutton', function () {
  var serverId = $(this).data('Id'); //this binds to html input
  renameApplication(serverId);
});
```

Comment: I was under the impression that data-* attributes broke on some older browsers..? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432174/how-to-store-arbitrary-data-for-some-html-tags

Comment: What says in that answer is that it is not XHTML 1.1 strict, if you see other answers regarding some old browsers, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6, the data-* work

Comment: Thanks. That's better than the solution I was going to come up with.