# What is the correct way to store some data in `<a>` anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i usually use `data-***` to store some data.

```
<a href="#" data-address="some data">click</a>
```

i can get it in jquery using

```
alert($("a").data("address"));
```

it works fine. but i want to know is it the right way of doing and is there any compatibility issues??

or does i need to use the `rel` ie:

```
<a href="#" rel="some data">click</a>

alert($("a").attr("rel"));
```

i updated a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs/XYZQK/

Comment: What data do you need to store in there? Abusing `rel` is never the right solution.

Comment: i want to store alots of html. so that i can use it in bootstrap model.

Comment: Attributes aren't really good places for HTML.

Comment: i updated a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs/XYZQK/

Comment: Why do you need to store all of this data in your anchor tag?

Comment: yes it can cause compatibility issue with some browsers.

Comment: @PankajKathiriya: What issues?

Comment: @Blender becuase `<a>` is in `for loop` and there are lots of datas(ie different models for <a>)

Comment: @PankajKathiriya it will be very helpful if you let me know the issues

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store arbitrary data for some HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432174/how-to-store-arbitrary-data-for-some-html-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the data to stored temporarily (ie only for the duration of the page) then using the [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) api is the right way

Answer (score 3):

the `rel` attribute when referrering to an `a` tag is for search engines to determine the relationship between the document and the one it's linking to.

the `data` attribute can be used by developers to make custom attributes while storing data in it.

that being said `data-***` is the correct way to store some data.

[MDN HTML attribute reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)

*DON'T USE REL FOR CUSTOM DATA STORAGE*

**COMPATIBILITY CONCERNS**

Since the `data` and `rel`(referrering to `a` tag) attributes are suppose to be ignored by browsers, you can use both, either/or. Although it's best practice to use the `data` tag to store 'data' .

---

**RICH SEARCH RESULTS**

[image]

if you want search engines to recongize certain links or elements as data describing your content, like page description, publish date, page image, so and so forth, you might want to read up on 'rich search result' and 'rich snippets' from google.

these link will start you out [Rich search results](http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1626952&topic=2642610&ctx=topic) or [About rich snippets and structured data](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/99170?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article about why you should not use rel, and what you could try if you're not sure about using data-.

http://www.sitepoint.com/rel-not-a-custom-attribute/

Bootstrap already makes heavy use of data-, no reason not to take it even further.

Comment: is there any compatibility issue in `data-***` i mean browser or os

Answer (score 1):

It is correct to store data with custom data attributes which starts with "data-".

It meets HTML5 specification.

See the following link.

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes

Answer (score 1):

You're abusing `data-` attributes, so for your use case, neither of them are correct (`rel` never is).

I would either change the structure of the HTML to accommodate the extra information (i.e. use other tags) or just store the content in a JavaScript object to begin with. Cramming it all into a single anchor tag isn't a good idea.

Comment: but on `<a>` click how can i supply these data to the `model`. does i need to write models for each `<a>`, and call using `<a href ='perticular model'>` that looks very bad, right??

Comment: @suhail: Model or modal? If it's a modal dialog, then just make a generic event handler that takes care of all of the links.

Comment: hey you are right. Now i getting errors. i am not getting full text.. any suggestions????

Comment: what do you mean by `other tags`. i get stuck there now.  :(.. you have a good insight...

Comment: now i workedout with jquery and ajax, and just remove the `data-` tags...hmmmmmmm :(