# What compatibility will I need to keep in mind for html data storing?

Tags: javascript, html

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432174/how-to-store-arbitrary-data-for-some-html-tags) one can store data within html tags, now my `DOCTYPE` header is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

**I am wondering what cross/backwards compatibility I should keep in mind of**, like which versions of which browsers will have problems if I tried using javascript to access a `output-file` attribute in a form tag. E.g.

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" output-file="export.log">
```

EDIT: the reason for my header is that i am adding onto an existing intranet system and they use that same header for every page and it was around before HTML5 (which ideally i would have wanted to use)

EDIT 2: i am well aware that i should use `data-` to prefix my attribute however i can use `console.log(document.getElementById("myForm").getAttribute("output-file"))` just fine and get the correct result, i figure someone would pick up on that and also explain possible problems cross/backwards compatibility

Comment: Out of interest, why did you choose the HTML 4.01 Transitional doctype (from 1999?) I'd be interested to understand your train of thought when you selected that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Why the HECK are you using a transitional doc type? Why not strict?*

Anyways - to answer your question, yes you can use HTML storage, but you should get the syntax right:

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" data-output-file="export.log">
```

Note the use of the `data-` prefix.

You can read this in javascript with:

```
var el = document.getElementById("myForm");
var filename = el.getAttribute("data-output-file");
el.setAttribute("data-output-file", "newName");
```

This is an excellent writeup:
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute--webdesign-9642

**EDIT**

The use of the `data-*` attributes is very well supported in all modern browsers, even as far back as IE.  You won't have any compatibility issues there.

To answer the other question: By using the `data-*` prefix you:

- Won't run into any issues with new html attributes are added later.  The `HTML5` standard as specifically set aside the `data-*` namespace for this purpose.
- In time, when [`<element>.dataSet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes), you'll be able to use that instead of the hacky `setAttribute` and `getAttribute`.

*Edit 2*

- This method works all the way back to IE6.
- If you do not use the data- prefix you run the risk of conflicts with new HTML5 attributes that come later.

Comment: This does not answer my question, **I am wondering what cross/backwards compatibility I should keep in mind of** not if it works or not as i know it does because `console.log(document.getElementById("myForm").getAttribute("output-file"))` outputs exactly what i expect and your link just talks about HTML5 which unless what i am doing is strictly HTML5 only (and thus my DOCTYPE is being ignored) then it doesn't help answer my question either.

Comment: i know it's proper to use the `data-` for validity but you question doesn't explain what problem i could come up to from ignoring the `data-` prefix, which falls back to my question about **what cross/backwards compatibility I should keep in mind of** (ie. not having the `data-` prefix make it invalid on say IE6)

Comment: @Memor-X If you have the `data-` prefix that makes it valid markup in HTML5 and invalid markup in all previous versions of HTML. If you do _not_ have the `data-` prefix that makes it invalid markup in **all** versions of HTML including 5.  But browsers are lenient and it's not going to bother them; it's _future_ compatibility you'll get by using `data-` — Using `HTML 4.01 Transitional` is what will cause you cross/backwards compatibility headaches, as it will throw modern browsers into Quirks Mode.