# How to enable onclick button features for all the entries in a table

Tags: html, jsp, button

I have created the device management system. For front end, I have a device table. In the table, the onclick button features are given. When I deactivate a device the delete button and activate button should be enabled. The problem is that this onclick feature doesn't work for all the entries in the table. Only the first device get this feature. How can I add a loop to resolve this problem?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYDMp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can have custom attributes in HTML 5. So, you can set custom attributes of different buttons with the row ID. Then in the script part, you can use the value of the `id` field to uniquely identify a button.

For example:

You can set the id's of your rows like `<button data-internalid="13"></button>`

In the script part, you can use the value of the `data-internalid` to find the equivalent button to disable after onClick();

I would really encourage you to do that on your own. :)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432174/how-to-store-arbitrary-data-for-some-html-tags)