# How can I create custom form required error text without adding excess code in my signup form?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have the required error message showing the input + id that is attached to it in the html

```
  <div class="form-validation">
            <input class="modal-input" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter your 
   password">
            <p>Error Message</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-validation">
            <input class="modal-input" id="password-confirm" type="password" placeholder="Confirm your password">
            <p>Error Message</p>
             </div>
```

So as you can see, the id's equal password and then password-confirm

Now the problem is I don't know how to create a custom text to change it from saying password-confirm to just saying password without overlapping with the id names.

Here's a picture below of what I mean

[image]

And here is the function that I wrote in order to get the "Password-confirm" to display

```
   function getFieldName(input) {
return input.id.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.id.slice(1);
   }
```

And here is my function the make sure the required fields show the error message with the getFieldName as the first word in the message

```
  function checkRequired(inputArr) {
inputArr.forEach(function (input) {
   if(input.value.trim() === '') {
       showError(input, `${getFieldName(input)} is required`);
   } else {
       showValid(input);
   }
});
  }
```

I tried to just target the type on the input instead of the id, but I run into another issue because the input type="text" displays "Text is required" when I want it to say "Username" so I need a method to be able to create any custom word + "is required"

So essentially I could customize it to say "WHATEVER is required"

Answer (score 0):

add a data tag to the html elements you are targeting.  and use it do display whatever you require to display.

refer to [How to store arbitrary data for some HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432174/how-to-store-arbitrary-data-for-some-html-tags) for details.