# Adding custom ( your own ) properties to DOM objects, OK?

Tags: javascript, html, object, dom, properties

```
<div id="theDiv"></div>

document.getElementByid('theDiv').myProperty='myValue';

if('undefined'!==typeof document.getElementById('theDiv').myProperty){
```

Is it ok and cross browser compatible to give DOM objects custom properties to be used later on?

If the properties only need to be **set and retrieved** via javascript can this be used instead of setAttribute / getAttribute?

Comment: Yes, this is perfectly legal and acceptable. Just be careful not to overwrite [something default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement). However keep in mind you'll possibly have to keep changing it in future versions, which will make maintaining your code rather difficult.

Comment: I have created a jQuery plugin to implement the same. Are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

### Edit 2014/07/21

According to @blgt comment and everything else I read, it seems that the [future proof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895560/javascript-dom-setting-custom-dom-element-properties/7895721#7895721) issue is the only problem you could encounter.

Actually, doing a jsperf on it shows [it's even a bit faster](http://jsperf.com/qssdqsdqd/3) than setAttribute / getAttribute

---

*Should be comment*

Maybe this answer may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3363501/3702797

or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895560/javascript-dom-setting-custom-dom-element-properties)

and particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7895721/3702797)

Comment: I know about setAttrbiute / getAttribute, but are there any issues with the notation I used above?

Comment: Updated answer but I'm no specialist sorry…

Comment: The "this answer" is particularly helpful. But I am curious if aside from the possibility of future-collisions, there are any downsides.

Comment: According to @blgt comment and everything else I read, it seems to be the only one, in fact, doing a jsperf on it shows [it's even a bit faster](http://jsperf.com/qssdqsdqd/3) than setAttribute / getAttribute