# JavaScript DOM document function to add 'for' attribute to a html tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have following working code in HTML and JS:

HTML:

```
<label class="slider-text" for="masterChannel">
```

JS:

```
const masterChannel = document.querySelector('#masterChannel');
//Do more stuff...
```

now my plan is to convert my entire html code to JavaScript and so far, I have this:

```
  var label = document.createElement("label");
  label.classList.add("slider-text");
  //here I need to add the 'for' attribute to 'label' tag
```

I was not able to find any method in JS to add for attribute to a tag and I am not sure if I can achieve the same result with a different approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append custom attributes to a DOM node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363463/append-custom-attributes-to-a-dom-node)

Comment: You haven't found `.setAttribute()`? You haven't tried `label.for = ...`?

Comment: Ah sorry, it'd be `label.htmlFor = "masterChannel";`

Comment: @Pointy I tired label.htmlFor but was not able to make my code work, but I think it's my mistake since Scott-Marcus pointed out my querySelector is not correct. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was not able to find any method in JS to add for attribute to a tag

Searching Google for "[add attribute to tag with javascript](https://www.google.com/search?q=add%20attribute%20to%20a%20tag%20with%20javascript&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS839US839&oq=add%20attribute%20to%20a%20tag&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0j0i22i30l3j69i60l2.5060j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)" yields several correct answers, the 1st being [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

```js
var label = document.createElement("label");
label.classList.add("slider-text");
label.setAttribute("for", "masterChannel");

console.log(label);
```

Additionally, as @Pointy mentioned, you can also use the [`.htmlFor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLLabelElement/htmlFor) DOM property on the object:

```js
var label = document.createElement("label");
label.classList.add("slider-text");
label.htmlFor = "masterChannel";

console.log(label);
```

And, by the way, the code in your question of:

```
const masterChannel = document.querySelector('#masterChannel');
```

would not get a reference to the label you showed with this HTML:

```
<label class="slider-text" for="masterChannel">
```

because `#` in `.querySelector()` refers to the `id` of an element and you have no `id` in your `label` element's code. For the HTML you showed, you could use:

```
const masterChannel = document.querySelector("[for='masterChannel']");
```

because `[]` represent the attribute selector in CSS.

Comment: Using `.htmlFor` instead of `.setAttribute()` yields the same output.