# Function Expected Error in javascript

Tags: javascript

for dynamically created check box when it is clicked i want to grab the attribute value.It is working in IE 8,9,10 but not working in IE 11,chrome shows function expected error

```
<input type=checkbox checked='checked' id='SymptomFailureCodeId' TabIndex='54' style='cursor:pointer;' onclick=ChkClickEvt(this);  FailureCodeId="1" >


function ChkClickEvt(Obj) { 
    alert(Obj.attributes("FailureCodeId"));
}
```

Comment: Is this a typo, or do you literally have this `onclick=ChkClickEvt(this);` where the command is not wrapped in `"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) instead:

```
Obj.getAttribute("FailureCodeId")
```

Or if you want to use `attributes` property don't use it as a method. It's a `NamedNodeMap`.

For example:

```
Obj.attributes["FailureCodeId"]
```

But be aware that this no longer supported on Firefox > 22 and many modern browsers. Read more about this at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.attributes)

Comment: thanks working.one more how to check null for Obj.attributes so that if it is null i can switch over to getattribute

Comment: Why do you need this check? Use always `getAttribute`. It's cross browser and have better support.

Answer (score 0):

A better method would be using [HTML5 data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Markup

```
<input type='checkbox' id='SymptomFailureCodeId' data-FailureCodeId="1" />
```

JavaScript

```
var article = document.querySelector('#SymptomFailureCodeId'),
          data = article.dataset;
console.log( data.FailureCodeId );
```

P.S: You would be golden with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/427262/17447) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/432174/17447)

P.P.S: I am fairly sure that making up custom attributes like that is not the best practice. I am searching for further evidence to back my argument. ;)